# Apache httpd does not accept file >2GB, LFS Support, 32bit

Tags: apache, large-files, 32-bit, apr

**Unable to upload Large file in apache httpd-2.4.48 (compiled as 32bit binary)**

Apache is compiled as 32bit package on 64bit processor,

below error is observed when we try to upload file >2GB.
[Mon Jul 26 22:05:10.750215 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22794] mod_authz_core.c(843): [client 10.188.103.247:63730] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives), referer: http://10.188.103.118/?MAIN=WELCOME
[Mon Jul 26 22:05:10.750465 2021] [contentwebserver:debug] [pid 22794] ccontentwebserver.cpp(1125): [client 10.188.103.247:63730] CContentWebServer:: SessionID=[ContentWebServer_10.188.103.247.138f674dea80ace6fa180df6e5a20dcb]   ignoreSessionTimeout=[1], referer: http://10.188.103.118/?MAIN=WELCOME
[Mon Jul 26 22:05:10.843785 2021] [core:debug] [pid 22794] protocol.c(1389): [client 10.188.103.247:63730] AH10242: **client sent invalid Content-Length (2785018852)**: /contentwebserver/upload, referer: http://10.188.103.118/Administration/SystemUpdates/nSystemUpdatesUpload.html?v=1625526276ta
[Mon Jul 26 22:05:10.843869 2021] [headers:debug] [pid 22794] mod_headers.c(890): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()

however, the upload operation is successful when the file size is <2GB without any issues.

We had tried compiling apache httpd-2.4.48 with **apr_cv_use_lfs64=yes** flag and confirmed from config.log

mod_contentwebserver.so is apache httpd module.

please let us know how to proceed further on this?

Comment: It's 2021, you're running a 32bit application on a 64bit machine, stumble upon a 32vs64bit problem and _all_ you do when you recompile the software yourself is to set a flag, _not_ compile it as 64bit binary? In case there is any necessity to keep 32bit: Let us know. otherwise: compile a 64bit binary, or use a distribution's repository version

Comment: Thanks for reply. we need to use apache httpd as 32binary as other dependent modules are compiled as 32bit binary. due to some reasons we cannot use 64bit apache httpd. it would be helpful if we can get any pointers to resolve this LFS in apache httpd. thanks